# How can the pseudo element detect the height of the non-pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/ZWw3Z/

```
<p>Text text text text text text text...</p>
```

```
p {
    background-color: blue;
}

p:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Essentially, the height of the pseudo element is too big. I want it to have the same height as the `p` element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To future readers, the effect was to have a bar appear over text on the left-hand side. To accomplish this, the OP was using `position: absolute;` on the psuedo element (`p:before`).

The error OP was encountering was because the psuedo-element was treating the `<body>` as it's relative position point - to fix, simply set `position: relative;` on the `<p>` tag.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* change the padding to something larger 
  than the width of the :before element to 
  add spacing for text
  */
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>text... text...</p>
```

Comment: You don't need an external container. The `p` itself contains `p:before` so you can simply relatively position the `p` instead.