# Make CSS pseudoelement :before same height as main element

Tags: css, counter, contenteditable, pseudo-element

I've been looking all over and failed to find a solution to this on my own. I'm trying to make a basic contenteditable code editor, and for the line numbers I have chosen to use a paragraph for each line with a counter set in a CSS pseudo element.

```css
.editor {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-family: "Consolas", "Monaco", "Courier New", monospace;
  counter-reset: line;
  width: 90%;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.editor p {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: line;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
}

.editor p:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(line);
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006;
  text-align: right;
  /*-webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet nunc non pulvinar luctus. Cras finibus turpis at arcu mollis, nec fermentum mi pretium. Aliquam suscipit lacus sapien, eu fringilla enim malesuada quis. Sed ut tincidunt erat.
    In posuere vulputate venenatis. Mauris quis porta magna. Phasellus pharetra in nisl et luctus. Etiam in ultrices risus. Morbi vel dapibus ex. Suspendisse gravida libero non malesuada congue. Pellentesque ut nunc diam.</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>
```

The problem is that if the paragraph is a bit longer the rest of the text will go beneath my counter pseudoelement. I want to strech the :before counter to be the same height as the paragraph.

I have tried using `position:relative` on the paragraph and `position:absolute; height:100%` on the p:before pseudoelement like explained here: [How can the pseudo element detect the height of the non-pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475430/how-can-the-pseudo-element-detect-the-height-of-the-non-pseudo-element)

This does not work in my case because I don't want the p:before element to go over and cover the paragraph, I just want the same behaviour as now, just want the `p:before` element to strech at the same height as the main `p`.

I also wouldn't want to have the line strech more than the width of the wrapper container. I've been trying many methods but failed to come to a solution.

Comment: You should show you HTML and CSS code, as needed to reproduce the issue, *in the question itself*.

Comment: I have posted a fiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/zppb29jw/ Think it's just easier this way

Comment: A fiddle is *not* a replacement for code, just a convenience. A question should be fully understandable without following any links (which may get broken some day).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Instead of `height`, rather use `position: relative;` for `p`, and `position: absolute;` for `:before`.

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zppb29jw/5/)

Here are the newly added CSS properties:

```
.editor p {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3.5em;


.editor p:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

**Edit**

It should be a second question :D

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in IE will not create a `br`, whereas in modern browsers it creates a `br` using `:after`. Here is to guarantee so that `p` tag does not remain empty:

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzkxmsk6/6)

```css
.editor {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-family: "Consolas", "Monaco", "Courier New", monospace;
  counter-reset: line;
  width: 90%;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.editor p {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: line;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3.5em;
}
.editor p:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(line);
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*-webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;*/
}
.editor p:after {
  content: " "
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet nunc non pulvinar luctus. Cras finibus turpis at arcu mollis, nec fermentum mi pretium. Aliquam suscipit lacus sapien, eu fringilla enim malesuada quis. Sed ut tincidunt erat.
    In posuere vulputate venenatis. Mauris quis porta magna. Phasellus pharetra in nisl et luctus. Etiam in ultrices risus. Morbi vel dapibus ex. Suspendisse gravida libero non malesuada congue. Pellentesque ut nunc diam.</p>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zppb29jw/3/
Seems there's no problem at all. I've been trying something simmilar, but was using height instead of te top, bottom and left positioning.
Thanks!

Comment: as always IE ruins everything, works great in Chrome and in firefox, but when you insert an empty line in IE it disappears. I know can make a javascript function to add a text node when enter is pressed but that will also open another pandora's box. Trying to avoid that...

Comment: very nice! that actually also solved another one of my problems because before when you pressed enter and left the paragraph empty, you couldn't select the paragraph. It's weird but I also tried with a after element last night, guess I was too sleepy :) 
Now it's pretty cool cause you can add a line break symbol after each line like this: 
`.editor p:after {
  content: "\21A9";
  color:#CCC;
}`

Comment: Superb (for a `flex` `li` in 2022 when the only time I type IE now is when I am abbreviating id est rather than shuddering with pain and blacking out from forgetting...that browser).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the line numbers and lines appear in table-like manner, the natural approach is to make them table: declare the editable area as table (in the CSS sense), make the lines rows, and make the generated line numbers table cells:

```css
.editor {
 display: tablek;
    border: 1px black solid;
    font-family: "Consolas", "Monaco", "Courier New", monospace;
    counter-reset: line;
 
 width:90%;
 height:350px;
 overflow:scroll;
 padding-left:0;
 margin-left:0;
 z-index:1;
 
}
.editor p {
 display: table-row;
    counter-increment: line;
 background-color:#FFF;
 text-align:left;
 margin:0px;
 z-index:2;
 outline: none;
 
}
.editor p:before {
 display: table-cell;
    width:2em;
 height:100%;
    border-right: 1px black solid;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    content: counter(line);
 color:#FFF;
 background-color:#006;
 text-align:right;
 
 /*-webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet nunc non pulvinar luctus. Cras finibus turpis at arcu mollis, nec fermentum mi pretium. Aliquam suscipit lacus sapien, eu fringilla enim malesuada quis. Sed ut tincidunt erat. In posuere vulputate venenatis. Mauris quis porta magna. Phasellus pharetra in nisl et luctus. Etiam in ultrices risus. Morbi vel dapibus ex. Suspendisse gravida libero non malesuada congue. Pellentesque ut nunc diam.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that's also pretty good, but again IE messes stuff up. You're not able to edit the text in the paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

```
.black_right{
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.black_right::after{
    content: " "; 
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 500px 0px #000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zppb29jw/2/

```
p {
    position:relative;
    left: 4em;
    ...

p:before {
    position:absolute;
    right:100%
    display:block;
    ...
```

is that ok for you?